# Writing a tcl script using event_register_syslog

Tags: tcl, command-line-interface, cisco-ios

I am a newby to this but I am tasked at writing a tcl script.
The script is to print a message on the command line "Warning, system error detected" when a syslog system_error is found.

Now I am completely new to tcl and all I know is that an event_register_syslog needs to be used. Other than that I am completely in the dark and do not know where to go or start.

There are no GUIs needed just the CLI.

Any help and support would be much appreciated.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19382325/720999).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a bit of code that should get you started:

```
#set result variable equal to contents of syslog  
set result [exec puts syslog]

#parse syslog line by line searching for error
foreach line [string trim [split $result "\n"]] {
    #regex the error string
    if {[regexp {Whatever Error Massage may look like!}]} {
        puts "Warning, system error detected"
    }
```

Here are some useful regex links for tcl:

1. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html

Comment: Hey, thanks a million for that. I would have included examples of work I have done but I literally have nothing, I feel like I am hitting my head off the wall. 
I am reading a tcl book and looking up examples online and trying to understand them and tweek them for my work but I just simply do not understand it.
I appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: I talked to my boss and showed him what you proposed and he said just keep it simple, so i simply did this;
    `::cisco::eem::event_register_syslog pattern SYSTEM_ERROR
    namespace import ::cisco::eem::*
    namespace import ::cisco::lib::*
    set msg "Warning, System Error Detected!"
    puts $msg`

He said that was fine and not to make it complicated. 
I have tried testing this and it does not work, would you have any advice on where I am going wrong? As I do want to keep this code as easy as possible

Comment: Take a look at this site: http://expertstudynotes.com/index.php?title=Cisco_IOS_Embedded_Event_Manager and this one http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6550/prod_white_paper0900aecd803a4dad_ps6815_Products_White_Paper.html